# JQuery grid view in Php

Tags: jquery

I'm making application. I am using JQuery, that retrieves data from MySQL database using php, and all data will be displayed in the grid. So, for this application I need a grid view plugin that will work better.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx).